# Android set Screen Lock support pin

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I used `devicePolicyMananger.resetPassword` to set lock screen pass . but i want to change the support pin that used when admin forgot password .
I mean change support pin pass.

Comment: Am I  Should use keyGurd?

Comment: What device type and Android version are you using? To my knowledge there is no support PIN in vanilla Android? Please provide more details on support PIN.

Comment: My phone is galaxy S4 . when i want to set a pass for screen lock , after confirming pass , i should inter a support pin . support pin can be used when pass is forgot , after 5 times you inter wrong pass you can inter support pin and reset screen lock.

Comment: @MarekPola My phone is galaxy S4 . when i want to set a pass for screen lock , after confirming pass , i should inter a support pin . support pin can be used when pass is forgot , after 5 times you inter wrong pass you can inter support pin and reset screen lock.

Comment: I suspect this is a Samsung specific function, it doesn't exist on Sony mobiles at least. Maybe Samsung has a proprietary API to reset the support PIN? /Marek (Sony Mobile employee)

Comment: @MarekPola tnx a lot